# Codeigniter Active Record 'where_or' grouping

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Is it possible to *group* and_where / or_where / or_like... statements together so as not to mix with other and/where statements.

Something that would result in

> WHERE city = 'My City' AND state = 'My State' AND (name LIKE %name1%
>   OR name LIKE %name2%)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.  `$this->db->where()` allows you to write clauses manually.  You could do this:

```
$this->db->where('city', 'My City');
$this->db->where('state', 'My State');
$this->db->where('(name LIKE %name1% OR name LIKE %name2%)', null, false);
```

Setting the third parameter for false prevents CodeIgniter from trying to add backticks to the clause.

Check out the [Active Record documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html).  The section titled **$this->db->where();** explains the four methods you can use to set **WHERE** clauses.

Answer (score 18):

I know this is a little late, but I found this post when looking into it and found a better solution than the one proposed by Sean.

```
$name = 'Bob';

$this->db->where('city', 'My City');
$this->db->where('state', 'My State');
$this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->like('name', $name);
    $this->db->or_like('name', $name);
$this->db->group_end();
```

Comment: This solution is for Codeigniter 3+ but not for Codeigniter 2

Answer (score 4):

These two functions `group_start()` and `group_end()` have been implemented in **CodeIgniter 3.0.3**. Here is little better implementation according to the original question.

```
$name1 = 'Bob';
$name2 = 'John';

$this->db->where('city', 'My City');
$this->db->where('state', 'My State');
$this->db->group_start();
$this->db->like('name', $name1);
$this->db->or_like(('name', $name2);
$this->db->group_end();
```