# CodeIgniter - Grouping where clause

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord, where-clause

I have this following query for CodeIgniter:

```
$q = $this->db->where('(message_from="'.$user_id.'" AND message_to="'.$this->auth_model->userdata['user_id'].'")')
            ->or_where('(message_from="'.$this->auth_model->userdata['user_id'].'" AND message_to="'.$user_id.'")')
            ->get('messages');
```

I want to write this query with completely active record.

I have tried something like this:

```
$from_where = array('message_from'=>$user_id, 'message_to'=>$this->auth_model->userdata['user_id']);
            $to_where   = array('message_from'=>$this->auth_model->userdata['user_id'],'message_to'=>$user_id);    
            $q = $this->db->where($from_where)
            ->or_where($to_where)
            ->get('messages');

            die($this->db->last_query());
```

The above code produces this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (`messages`) WHERE `message_from` = '2' AND `message_to` = '1' OR `message_from` = '1' OR `message_to` = '2'
```

But this is what I want to produce:

```
SELECT * FROM (`messages`) WHERE (message_from="2" AND message_to="1") OR (message_from="1" AND message_to="2")
```

There are similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470267/grouping-where-clauses-in-codeigniter) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748140/codeigniter-active-record-where-or-grouping), but thosedid not provide a real solution for me.

How's this possible, If not via core libraries, is there an extension which allows writing such queries?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sub query way of codeigniter to do this for this purpose you will have to hack codeigniter. like this
Go to system/database/DB_active_rec.php Remove public or protected keyword from these functions

```
public function _compile_select($select_override = FALSE)
public function _reset_select()
```

Now subquery writing in available And now here is your query with active record

```
$this->db->where('message_from','2');
$this->db->where('message_to','1');

$subQuery1 = $this->db->_compile_select();
$this->db->_reset_select();


$this->db->where('message_from','1');
$this->db->where('message_to','2');

$subQuery2 = $this->db->_compile_select();
$this->db->_reset_select();

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where("$subQuery1");
$this->db->or_where("$subQuery2");
$this->db->get('messages');
```

Look at this answer of mine. This shows how to use sub queries. This will help
[Using Mysql WHERE IN clause in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023318/using-mysql-where-in-clause-in-codeigniter/11031431#11031431)

EDITES

Yes i have done it
Rewrite the query this way exactly you want

```
$this->db->where('message_from','2');
$this->db->where('message_to','1');

$subQuery1 = $this->db->_compile_select(TRUE);
$this->db->_reset_select();


$this->db->where('message_from','1');
$this->db->where('message_to','2');

$subQuery2 = $this->db->_compile_select(TRUE);
$this->db->_reset_select();

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where("($subQuery1)");
$this->db->or_where("($subQuery2)");
$this->db->get('messages');
```

Compile select is with true parameter. Will not produce select clause. This will produce

```
SELECT * FROM (`messages`) WHERE (`message_from` = '2' AND `message_to` = '1') OR (`message_from` = '1' AND `message_to` = '2')
```

Comment: Thanks, I also have thought about using subqueries back then, but gave it up because of speed concerns. Would using subqueries will slow down the process a lot?

Comment: this i haven't tested try to use sub queries where the whole query is required for only where condition i haven't tested it yet.if subquery is dependant it will slow down the process insted join will do things faster