# Combination of AND and OR clauses

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to implement the following mysql statement in CodeIgniter.

```
select * from table_name 
         where deleted = 0 and (id = "18" or name = "efgh" or imei = "1244");
```

I have written the following statements in CodeIgniter:

```
$this->db->where('deleted', 0);
$this->db->or_where('id', $this->table_name->id);
$this->db->or_where('imei', $this->table_name->imei);
$this->db->or_where('name', $this->table_name->name);
$result= $this->db->get('table_name')->result();
```

But these two statements are giving different outputs. Could any one please point out the error in the CodeIgniter statement? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this :-

```
   $where = "deleted='0' AND (id='18' OR name='efgh' OR imei='1244')";
   $this->db->where($where);
   $result= $this->db->get('table_name')->result();
```

For more details You can visit :-

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
$this->db->where('deleted', 0);
$this->db->where("(id='18' OR name='efgh' OR imei='1244')", NULL, FALSE);
$result = $this->db->get('table_name')->result();
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happened to me before.

I coulnt figure out with `$this->db` function.

And i modify `system/database/DB_active_rec.php` `_compile_select()` function

**Original:** Line 1746

```
if (count($this->ar_like) > 0) {
  if (count($this->ar_where) > 0) {
    $sql .= "\nAND ";
  }
  $sql .= implode("\n", $this->ar_like);
}
```

**My changes:**

```
if (count($this->ar_like) > 0) {
  if (count($this->ar_where) > 0) {
    $sql .= "\nAND ("; // open parenthesis for where and like command
  }
  $sql .= implode("\n", $this->ar_like);
  if (count($this->ar_where) > 0) {
    $sql .= "\n)"; // close parenthesis and sample sql text > WHERE column = x AND (LIKE QUERIES)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes activerecord has problem using or, if you use activerecord it will not add start and end brackets for or condition then compare with and your query will be like this

```
select * from table_name where deleted = 0 and id="18" or name = "efgh" or imei = "1244";
```

to use it

```
$where = 'deleted = 0 and (id="18" or name = "efgh" or imei = "1244")';

$this->db->where($where);
```

Comment: Can we write $where with `$this->db->where` or `$this->db->or_where`? I dont like string query.

Comment: hi check this post can help you you can use both methods http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186491/codeigniter-grouping-where-clause

Comment: they are not useful. They do modify system file too. Im searching code that without modification system files.

Answer (score 0):

```
There is two way to do the same thing.
first 
$condition = "deleted='0' AND (id='18' OR name='efgh' OR imei='1244')";
$this->db->where($condition);
$result= $this->db->get('table_name')->result();
 and 
write your costume query 

$this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');
```

Hope it will help you.